Implementing client side logger with console.log capabilities
in order to extend console.log in the browser with a few extras (like a timestamp and loglevel) I came up with the following implementation:
  const LOG_LEVELS = {
    DEBUG: 0,
    INFO: 1,
    WARN: 2,
    ERROR: 3,
    NONE: 4,
  };

  const Logger = {
    debug:
      loglevel === LOG_LEVELS.DEBUG
        ? Function.prototype.bind.call(
            console.log,
            console,
            new Date().toISOString() + ": [DEBUG]"
          )
        : function () {},
    info:
      loglevel <= LOG_LEVELS.INFO
        ? Function.prototype.bind.call(
            console.log,
            console,
            new Date().toISOString() + ": [INFO]"
          )
        : function () {},
    warn:
      loglevel <= LOG_LEVELS.WARN
        ? Function.prototype.bind.call(
            console.log,
            console,
            new Date().toISOString() + ": [WARN]"
          )
        : function () {},
    error:
      loglevel <= LOG_LEVELS.ERROR
        ? Function.prototype.bind.call(
            console.error,
            console,
            new Date().toISOString() + ": [ERROR]"
          )
        : function () {},
  };

It has the advantage of sustaining the file and line-of-code information the same way as console.xxx calls are already doing that.
But: Obviously the date information is being generated together with the bind and not when calling Logger.debug etc., so all the log entries are showing the same date/time information.
Is there a way (maybe using apply?) to generate the date information at the time the Logger.xxxx functions execute? I tried a few things but none of them came even close. That's why I post the original code.

I came up with a workaround ... even though I would rather have it solved differently
With this
  const LOG_LEVELS = {
    DEBUG: 0,
    INFO: 1,
    WARN: 2,
    ERROR: 3,
    NONE: 4,
  };

  const Logger = {
    debug:
      loglevel === LOG_LEVELS.DEBUG
        ? function () {
            const timestamp = new Date().toISOString() + ": [DEBUG]";
            return Function.prototype.bind.call(
              console.log,
              console,
              timestamp
            );
          }
        : function () {},
    info:
      loglevel <= LOG_LEVELS.INFO
        ? function () {
            const timestamp = new Date().toISOString() + ": [INFO]";
            return Function.prototype.bind.call(
              console.log,
              console,
              timestamp
            );
          }
        : function () {},
    warn:
      loglevel <= LOG_LEVELS.WARN
        ? function () {
            const timestamp = new Date().toISOString() + ": [WARN]";
            return Function.prototype.bind.call(
              console.log,
              console,
              timestamp
            );
          }
        : function () {},
    error:
      loglevel <= LOG_LEVELS.ERROR
        ? function () {
            const timestamp = new Date().toISOString() + ": [ERROR]";
            return Function.prototype.bind.call(
              console.error,
              console,
              timestamp
            );
          }
        : function () {},
  };

everything seems to be working. The only thing I need to do is to replace Logger.debug("xxxx") with Logger.debug()("xxxx"). It's not great, but it works flawlessly.
